# magicalrecord deleting non-imported data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

Imagine the following relation in CoreData

```
Recipe < --- >> Ingredient
```

I'm using MagicalRecord to regularly import the server database (JSON API) with my local CoreData database.

So, if I import `Recipe 1` with `Ingredient 1` like this:

```
{
  id:1,
  name: "Recipe 1",
  ingredients: [{
    name: 'Ingredient 1'
  }]
}
```

So for so good, MagicalRecord creates the two entities and links them together.

The problem appears when the server changes to the following:

```
{
  id:1,
  name: "Recipe 1",
  ingredients: [{
    name: 'Ingredient 2' <-- Notice here
  }]
}
```

What MagicalRecord does is create the `Ingredient 2`record (correct), link it to be the *only* ingredient for `Recipe 1`(correct). But if I search for Ingredients, I found *2* records on my CoreData database.

So the questions is, is it possible to keep track of "deleted" objects when importing, and deleting them?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is that MagicalRecord seems to be importing duplicates. This problem should have been resolved in a recent update, however, if you're still having issues, I suggest opening a ticket on the [project issues page](https://github.com/magicalpanda/magicalrecord/issues)

Comment: well no I don't think so. Clearly I'm associated the same Recipient with a different Ingredient (Ingredient 2). So I just want the "Ingredient 1" entity and relation to be gone.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked around this problem by following this process.

1. Run a query on your core data store that will return the values you expect for any given server request.  Find all the objectIDs for every object found by the query that is expected to be returned by the server.
2. Make the server request and import the data.
3. Before saving get all updated objects from the context you just used to import the data.
4. Delete any object in your original list of objectIDs that is not in your list of updated objectIDs

This approach should achieve the desired behaviour for any given request.  Just be aware you will still possibly be deleting records referenced from elsewhere, so only use this approach if they can be recreated by other future requests.

**Import Code**

```
NSArray *existingObjectIDs = [self existingObjectIDsForYourQuery];

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
                    [Recipe MR_importFromObject:response inContext:localContext];
                    NSArray *objectIDs = [[[localContext updatedObjects] allObjects] valueForKey:@"objectID"];
                    [self deleteLocalObjectsWithObjectIDs:existingObjectIDs excludingImportedObjectIDs:objectIDs];
}];
```

**Delete Code**

```
- (void)deleteLocalObjectsWithObjectIDs:(NSArray *)existingObjectIDs excludingImportedObjectIDs:(NSArray *)importedObjectIDs {
    NSMutableArray *objectsToDelete = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:existingObjectIDs];

    for ( NSManagedObjectID *objectID in importedObjectIDs ) {
        [objectsToDelete removeObject:objectID];
    }

    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        for ( NSManagedObjectID *objectID in objectsToDelete ) {
            NSManagedObject *object = [localContext existingObjectWithID:objectID error:nil];

            if ( object ) {
                [localContext deleteObject:object];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just change the name of `Ingredient` on the server if this is what you're using as the primary key. MagicalRecord and Core Data has no clue which record was updated all it knows is that no `Ingredient` with that name exists and it'll create a new record for you and map the relationship from `Recipe`. You'll have to manually delete any records in your local app database that do not exist in the JSON payload.

Consider the following:

You have no primary key for your `Ingredient` object. You have to let MagicalRecord know what key is primary (when no "ingredientID" attribute exists.

You do this by going into your Core Data model and selecting the `Ingredient` entity. Next, add a "relatedByAttribute" key in the user info in the data model inspector, with "name" as the value.

Next go into your `Recipe` entity, select the relationship for `Ingredient` and also add a "relatedByAttribute" key and "name" value in the user dictionary for the relationship. This way MagicalRecord now knows to look up any existing `Ingredient` records by the "name" attribute and it'll map to the existing record if one exist, other create a new entity and link `Recipe` to it.

You can read more information here: http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/, specially the section "Related by keys" is of interest to you.

Again, as mentioned above, you've only updated the name, which means you should probably delete any `Ingredient`s for the current `Recipe`. If you delete the object on the server, you will need to delete it in your local data base as well.

If you're still having problems I would suggest you create a category class on `Recipe` in which you manually look up any records that matches the name and create/update accordingly. But don't forget to delete records that don't exist in the payload but exist locally.